# is it possible to remove a mouseListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I added mouseListener to a button and when mouse moved to it it performs some action. I added an actionListener to same button and it removes the button. My question is: when I try to remove the button I get runtime error. How can I remove the button?

Comment: Please show us a short example that can reproduce your problem, together with the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding:

> is it posibble to remove a mouseListener in Java

Yes, simply call `myComponent.removeMouseListener(myMouseListener);` and it's gone. You of course would need a reference to the said MouseListener.

Also regarding:

> I added mouseListener to a button

You generally don't want to do this, and I'd be interested to know how you're using this. JButtons should get ActionListeners added to them and not MouseListeners.

> and when mouse moved to it it performs some action.

If it's to listen for hovering, you might be better adding a ChangeListener to the JButton's model and query for `isRollover()`. -- OR -- perhaps what you really need is to set the JButton's tool tip text via the `setToolTipText(String text)` method.

> I added an actionListener to same button and it removes the button. My question is: when I try to remove the button I get runtime error. How can i remove the button?

Here we're stuck since we don't have access to pertinent code or your error message. If you need more help, please improve the question by providing pertinent code, preferably as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. Also post the complete error message as well as an indication of what lines cause the error (something the error message will tell you).

Comment: Guys, thanks everyone. I solved the problem with carrying the previous panel to a location where is not visible. I tried the removeMouseListener method but I couldn't. Probably I missed something. So the last way that I used was so convenient for me.